# Python: Find and Remove Child from XML file and output to new file

Tags: python, xml

I have an XMl file below. I want to be able to delete all childs plan that are not  called john and output to new file.

```
    <data>
        <plan_main>
            <plan>
               <name>John</name>
               <id>1</id>
            </plan>
            <plan>
               <name>Charlie</name>
               <id>2</id>
            </plan>
         </plan_main>
       <location>
            <country>
               <code>GB</code>
            </country>
            <country>
               <code>DE</code>
            </country>
       </location>
    </data>
```

I've tried the following code but get an ValueError Not in list

```
for plan in root.findall('./plan_main/plan'):
  name = plan.find('name').text
  if name =! "john":
    root.remove(plan)

tree.write('output.xml')
```

I want my output file to look like this:

```
       <data>
        <plan_main>
            <plan>
               <name>John</name>
               <id>1</id>
            </plan>
         </plan_main>
       <location>
            <country>
               <code>GB</code>
            </country>
            <country>
               <code>DE</code>
            </country>
       </location>
    </data>
```

However I get the following error:

```
     ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: Are you using `lxml` ?

Comment: No, I mean't what library are you using, you didn't mention that

Comment: Import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `=!` is just a copy/paste mistake. The issue is that you are trying to remove the element from `root` node using [`Element.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove) method, but `.remove()` only removes elements if they are direct children of `root`.

If you want to use `ElementTree` itself, you can change the XPath to loop over all the `plan_main` elements, and then for each `plan_main` element, loop over all its children, and if any children's name is not `john` , remove it. Example-

```
for plan_main in root.findall('./plan_main'):
    for plan in plan_main:
        name = plan.find('name').text
        if name.lower() != "john":
            plan_main.remove(plan)
```

Demo -

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> s = """    <data>
...         <plan_main>
...             <plan>
...                <name>John</name>
...                <id>1</id>
...             </plan>
...             <plan>
...                <name>Charlie</name>
...                <id>2</id>
...             </plan>
...          </plan_main>
...        <location>
...             <country>
...                <code>GB</code>
...             </country>
...             <country>
...                <code>DE</code>
...             </country>
...        </location>
...     </data>"""
>>> root = ET.fromstring(s)
>>> for plan_main in root.findall('./plan_main'):
...     for plan in plan_main:
...         name = plan.find('name').text
...         if name.lower() != "john":
...             plan_main.remove(plan)
...
>>> print(ET.tostring(root).decode('utf-8'))
<data>
        <plan_main>
            <plan>
               <name>John</name>
               <id>1</id>
            </plan>
            </plan_main>
       <location>
            <country>
               <code>GB</code>
            </country>
            <country>
               <code>DE</code>
            </country>
       </location>
    </data>
```

---

If you can use [`lxml.etree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.4.4) , you can make small change to your code to get it working, by getting the direct parent of the child you want to remove, using `.getparent()` method. Example -

```
for plan in root.findall('./plan_main/plan'):
    name = plan.find('name').text
        if name.lower() != "john":
            plan.getparent().remove(plan)
```